# Start Android Java VM from native C code NDK (ffmpeg mediacodec use)

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, android-mediacodec, dalvik

I managed to [cross-compile `ffmpeg` using the NDK](https://github.com/Javernaut/ffmpeg-android-maker) for *armv8a* *api 27* with `MediaCodec` hardware acceleration support.

Using root after setting permissions, folders and setting properly `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` etc. I can run it without problems on a terminal session (ssh). Only if I don't try to use the `-hwaccel` option.

If try to run something using `-hwaccel`, like:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -an -hwaccel mediacodec -c:v hevc_mediacodec -i rtsp://user:pass@192.168.0.100:554/onvif1 -f null - -benchmark
```

I get the error bellow about `No Java virtual machine`.

```
...
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://user:pass@192.168.0.100:554/onvif1':
  Metadata:
    title           : H.265 Video, RtspServer_0.0.0.2
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 10 fps, 10 tbr, 90k tbn, 10 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
[amediaformat @ 0x7e2ea27300] No Java virtual machine has been registered
[hevc_mediacodec @ 0x7e2eb44f00] Failed to create media format
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (hevc_mediacodec) -> wrapped_avframe (native))
Error while opening decoder for input stream #0:0 : Generic error in an external library
```

Would it be possible to **start** (create or launch?) the Dalvik Java VM directly from the C code? I don't even know if those are correct terms. Make it visible for `ffmpeg`?

Any information that will help a ***Android Newbie*** get on his feet will be greatly appreciated. If that is possible I would write a little patch on the `ffmpeg` code.

I really would not like to package this in an app only to be able to test around with this.

Comment: I'm leaning toward no as Android apps run in ART/Dalvik VM so it isn't possible to start from C code. Anything linked against NDK lives inside an Android app. Also see: https://source.android.com/devices/media

Comment: https://www.programmersought.com/article/58963128680/

Answer (score 1):

If you build your executable using the AOSP tools, you can [instantiate an `AndroidRuntime`](https://devarea.com/creating-a-java-vm-from-native-code), and that will give you the JVM, see also the [app_process](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/cmds/app_process/app_main.cpp) command.

The conventional way to compile something for AOSP is to follow the [official instructions](https://source.android.com/setup/build/building) and add your executable to the build. But you can try to use the system headers and extract the shared libraries to link with from your device (or emulator).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am still trying to find out how to compile using the AOSP tools. Also trying to compile your [javaNative.cpp](https://github.com/DiscoverSDK/Android-Internals/blob/master/JavaFromNative/javaNative.cpp) if you could provide more details would be awesome. Thanks anyway

Comment: Well, it would be an exaggeration to call this `javaNative.cpp` mine. Note that it most likely won't compile these days – too many changes have happened in AOSP in the last 5 years.

Comment: Thanks! Well, since I'm a newbie on the android world I am finally accepting that using the android studio will be easier. Create a simple jar to call ffmpeg as a shared library (I will also have to modify it a bit) with `app_process` will be easier.

Comment: Oh yes, it's much easier to work from a regular (Java or Kotlin) app unless you *must* to go for command line. You won't need root, too.

Comment: Have a look at [this project](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit) that wraps ffmpeg nicely for Android (and other environments).

Comment: Thanks. I started with that. That's the approach that I didn't want to follow. Killing my pride heheh yeah that seams it will be easier to learn how to make an app. Thanks for all help!